# how to block the porn websites

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am using broadband connection in my home. I have "Tenda F3 300Mbps" router. I want to block all the porn websites or sexual content in the devices which is connected to my router through wifi.

I had block the porn content in my computer using the Open DNS proxy

```
208.67.222.123 
208.67.220.123
```

Now I want to block same thing in the devices which is connected though my wifi. How can I do this? I had made the changes instructed below, but it does not work.

Comment: This is a weak question. Google shows the answer,  and I assume you looked there first. So what have you tried and what worked?

Comment: I had tried to block these websites by changing the settings in the router but that does not worked for me

& it is not an weak question, don't you know the answer

Comment: Change the router DNS to the Open DNS proxy addresses.

Comment: Sorry for the late. I will check & get back to you on this.

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: If you can ever figure out a way to actually block all porn then you'll have money thrown at you.  Figuring out what the actual content of a page is for a machine is currently beyond our machine intelligence capability.  There are black lists of known sites but new sites crop up all the time and machines don't just "know" they're porn.

Comment: Yeap that is correct but many people who are using the routers they had blocked porn for safety purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in a comment, changing the router's DNS to the OpenDNS DNS servers will work. OpenDNS has a handy how-to and allows you to choose what types of content to block for requests from your network.

HOWEVER, this only blocks access for those devices using the network's provided DNS servers, and you can get around it by simply changing the device's DNS settings to a unblocked DNS service.

**UPDATE: Found Tenda F3 300 DNS Change How-To**

I found this with some simple googling: http://setuprouter.com/router/tenda/w300d/dns.htm

Assuming it is correct you:

1. Get your **OpenDNS** account set up and get the DNS information from them.
2. Login to the Tenda F3 Router interface.
3. Click on **Network** at the top of the page.
4. Click on **DHCP** on the left side of the page.
5. Click on **DHCP Server** on the left side of the page.
6. Enter the **OpenDNS** DNS servers into the **Primary DNS** and **Secondary DNS** fields on the page.
7. Click **Save**.

Any devices connected to the network will need to be rebooted or disconnected and reconnected to the network in order to pick up the new settings.

**UPDATE**

Go to the OpenDNS test page https://www.opendns.com/welcome/

If it shows you a large red X and says that you are not yet using OpenDNS, then you have not yet set up your network correctly and you need to go through the previous steps again or give us more information than you have so far.

If the page tells you that OpenDNS is working correctly then you have set up your network correctly and if you are still seeing sites you do not wish to see then, as I have stated several times so far, you must login to OpenDNS and follow their instructions for setting up your account to block the desired types of content.

Comment: How to do this using my router setting

Comment: I don't have a map of the Tenda F3's menus. OpenDNS does have a how-to that covers most routers. You'll typically find DNS settings on your router in the Networking section, but you may need to consult Tenda support to make sure you're putting the information in the correct place.

Comment: Okzz  i also don't know

Comment: See the updated post.

Comment: I had done what u have suggested me but still the content is not bloc in devices

Comment: I had tried your solution it works only for small websites it does not blocking the big porn websites like xvidoes, pornhub etc.

Comment: The fact that some sites are getting blocked means the filtering is working. That it is not blocking all that you wish means you need to check the settings in the OpenDNS control panel.

Comment: Do you know any other changes or how  to set the DNS

Comment: From your comment I assume you'd already applied the DNS blocking in the router configuration. That is how you do this. OpenDNS then has to know your ISP IP address so they can associate your preferred filtering settings with your actual connection, and you have to set those preferred filtering settings in their control panel.

Comment: Perhaps you can help us by telling us EXACTLY what you have done so far. Have you entered the DNS settings in the Router? Have you configured an OpenDNS account and followed ALL of their directions?

Comment: I had done DNS setting in the router

Comment: Then you need to configure your OpenDNS account as I specified a few comments back and in the original answer.

Comment: I had done same as u instructed in your answer but still top sites are running

Comment: So you went into the OpenDNS control panel and told it what sorts of sites to block and you've installed the IP address reporting utility on one of your computers to notify OpenDNS if your public IP changes?

Comment: I have done all this myself on my own home network for some basic filtering for my children and it is working perfectly. I am using a different router than you are, but DNS works the same.

Comment: So can you guide me how you had blocked all sites on your home network

Comment: Bad question - but good answer! +1